# Issues adding .editable function to a .sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, contenteditable

Here is my Fiddle I am currently working with. http://jsfiddle.net/Nemi9/76JPk/29/

I want keep everything sortable, but want to add the editable function to all the ul on a click or mouse down. I am currently trying to make each list and any new items added to each list .editable they are currently all .sortable.  The top code is the code I am currently using to try to make lines 17- 45 in HTML editable when clicked on. I want the person to be able to click on each listed item and add their own text inside the field.

I put contenteditable= true into each list id

These lines below are 63- 66 in .JS

```
var editable1 =$("#names,#homes,#purchased").editable();

    $("#names,#homes,#purchased",editable1).click(function(ev){
    $("#names,#homes,#purchased").input(type=submit)
```

Here is my current HTML

```
 <div class="box1">
   <h3>Needed Items</h3>
     <ul id="names" contenteditable="true"/>
       <li class="ui-state-default">Carrot</li>
       <li class="ui-state-default">Onion</li>
       <li class="ui-state-default">Water</li>

   </ul>

</div>



  <div class="box2"> 
     <h3>Home Items</h3>
      <ul id="home" contenteditable="true"/>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Cookies</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Milk</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Chicken</li>

   </ul>

</div>


   <div class="box3">
      <h3>Purchased Items</h3>
       <ul id="purchased" contenteditable="true"/>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Potato</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Rum</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Coke</li>


   </ul>

   </div>
```

Comment: What actually do you want? As per your example OP it is working as intended.

Comment: Do you want to add an another class "editable" to all the <ul>s ?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want keep everything sortable, but want to add the editable function to all the ul on click or mouse down.

Comment: I've tried this but it overrided my sortable and submit button functions.   

      
     var editable1 =$("#names,#homes,#purchased").editable()
      
      $('editable1')[0].onmousedown = function() {
          this.focus();
      };
  });